# run matlab2017 script on ubuntu server command line

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I am using matlab 2017 on ubuntu 16.04 server without GUI interface, and I want to know the way to run my script .m on terminal. I am trying in the following way, but I have no answer.

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "p = path; path(p,'/home/ubuntu/code/');script.m"
```

Please let me know the error. Thanks

Comment: What makes you think its not working?

Comment: Please let us know the error as well.

Comment: the error I have is command not found. Should I change the path?

Answer (score 0):

you should take out the .m in command line launch, something like

`matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r script`

Comment: Thanks, I just tested changing the export path, and works